Is there a way to set command line options at the top of a Haskell file?
I have some Haskell source files with which I interact with and I was wondering:

Is there a way to set command line options at the top of the file?

I refer to GHCi command line options that we use with the :set command (I like to use the +s option, for example, to see time and memory allocation info for each execution). I want to tell the compiler what options to set when loading that source file. Something like this:
-- Maybe some option here...
module Main (main) where

-- Code ...

I know that I could simply choose the flags I want and run it, though I think it could be more straightforward sometimes to just run the script without having to worry. Is this possible?
Another question I have is, if there were a way to do this, if I made an executable with the file, would it carry within it the options set for GHCi? (I don't think so, but I want to know otherwise).

Typically you use the {-# LANGUAGE ... #-} pragma.

Some options can indeed be passed with an OPTIONS_GHC pragma [ghc-doc], like:
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

module Main (main) where
    -- …
These then will give that directive to the GHC compiler that compiles the file.
For language extensions, the LANGUAGE pragma [ghc-doc] is normally used: this is more standardized, so other Haskell compilers should understand these as well.

Thank you so much Willem! Now I'm looking deeper into pragmas! I wouldn't know what is this syntax called. Another question, if I created custom flags/options, I could set them with pragmas just like the ones that already exist, right?

Normally, yes. There are perhaps a few options that are "project"-wide, but most options have a file-like granularity.
